# How to create an image/installer of multiple installed programs on Windows 7 for free?

Tags: windows, installation, backup, imaging

**Note: Without creating a fresh new image.**

I have a base Windows 7 OS (with some software)

I want to install multiple applications (20-30), and then capture all these installations in a single image/installer, so that this could be used on multiple PCs. When I am installing the additional software, I want it to capture file changes, registry changes and any new directories added.

Then I would simply "extract" this on another PC for fast installation. 
Kinda like a **standalone incremental backup/restore for free**.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I backup entire installations of a program, instead of just manually backing up individual files?](http://superuser.com/questions/68721/how-can-i-backup-entire-installations-of-a-program-instead-of-just-manually-bac)

Comment: maybe. clonezilla seems promising. :)

Comment: domain? all on the same network? clonezilla will give you problems with windows. You need to use SysPrep then......and do any of these apps you are going to install need serials/keys/etc?

Comment: Are any of the programs on you list supported by [Ninite](http://ninite.com/)

Comment: When cloning/sysprep'ing machines, you need to check each application's documentation.  Some applications registry/ini/etc files might need to be modified manually beforehand.

Comment: few of the apps are in Ninite's list. While most of them are free to download, two will require a serial.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Windows Post-Install Wizard is what I was looking for.

Silent and automatic installs of applications!