# Can I backup only the application folder in Windows?

Tags: windows, backup

If I have an application that is installed in the 'program file' and I want to take a backup of the application in case any disaster happen. If I take a backup for only the application folder without the registry.

If later, something wrong happen, and I have to uninstall the application. After doing the uninstall.

Can I just use the old backup folder of the application without installing it again through the setup file? Will it work if I replaced in the same place as it is in the program file before?

If not, then how can I restore it back? And what should I backup then?

Comment: Related: [How can I backup entire installations of a program, instead of just manually backing up individual files?](http://superuser.com/q/68721/194694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All programs are different. Try and find "portable" installation programs; these typically run from a single folder and can be backed up in the way you describe.

Windows programs are likely to add/modify the registry and the failure to marry the file backups with the registry are likely to cause problems when restoring/copying to another computer from backup.

Linux programs can update `/etc` files and folders, but are more (in some cases) resistant to the issue, or at least offer detail of what how to backup.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the application. If the application stores its settings locally, for example in an .ini or .xml file, then you can just backup the whole folder and restore it. If settings are stored in the registry, this method probably won't work, however, you could install the application from scratch, and then replace the application folder with your backup.

Some applications recreate specific registry keys at startup (for example MS Office), if they are missing, but that doesn't mean they will create installation paths in a registry that has never heard of them before.

If your application requires libraries, they will need to be registered, which is done in the installation process, so that would make restoring your backup folder without installation useless.